# Firefox Flash & Quicktime plugins under Debian and OpenSolaris?

Tags: firefox, flash, debian, quicktime, opensolaris

Please excuse this newbie question:

I've got installations of Debian 5 and OpenSolaris 2009.06, both of which have Firefox 3.5.3 setup and running. Unfortunately:

1.Firefox under Debian can't play YouTube videos (I am assuming this is Flash?) nor Quicktime trailers from e.g. Apple.com/trailers.

2.Firefox under OpenSolaris can't play Quicktime videos.

Does anyone know how to get plugins to solve these problems? If not, pointers to helpful resources would be great too! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the non-free Adobe Flash Player under Debian you can follow these insructions:

http://www.debianadmin.com/how-to-install-adobe-flash-in-debian-etchlennysid.html

For QuickTime, you have several choices.  Notably, you can install mozilla-plugin-vlc, xine-plugin, or mozilla-mplayer.

Can't help you with OpenSolaris, but I suspect at least some of those packages exist for it.

Comment: Problem: the instructions in the link seem to be outdated as my apt-get said: 'Package flashplugin-nonfree is not available, but is referred to by another package.....this may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source'
Also, the official Flash plugin tar.gz file from Adobe only has the .so file and not the installer as said on the website. I tried to copy the libflashplugin.so file to my firefox/plugins directory but it did not show up. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the "contrib" keyword to the repositories in sources.list?  Have you added the non-free repository?  

If you visit http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ from a Linux box, you will be prompted to download an Ubuntu deb, which should work fine on the current Debian.  (I haven't tested this.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want Flash on OpenSolaris, the easiest way to get it is to go to [pkg.sun.com](http://pkg.sun.com/) and sign up. That will get you access to a precompiled Flash which fits right in the Firefix Sun distributes.

Thre reason it isn't in the default distribution is that Sun can not redistribute Flash.

Comment: interesting, but reread the question: OP doesn't mention a problem with *Flash* on OpenSolaris, only on Debian.